# Remove extra part in remoteClientAddress string in .xslt in MULE server 3.3.0 CE?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, wsdl, mule

In my configuration.xml in MULE server 3.3.0 CE, I pass MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS to .xslt file, below I copied my codes :

```
    <logger 
  message="#[message.inboundProperties['MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS']]" 
  level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

To pass IP address to XSLT, store it in a variable and pass that.

```
    <set-variable 
  variableName="remoteClientAddress" 
  value = "#[message.inboundProperties['MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS']]"/>
```

Pass it to XSLT as:

```
<xm:xslt-transformer xsl-file="xsltFileName.xslt">
  <xm:context-property 
    key="remoteClientAddress" 
    value="#[remoteClientAddress]"/>
</xm:xslt-transformer>
```

In my XSLT, declared a param variable

```
<xsl:param  name="remoteClientAddress" />
```

and then use this variable as

```
<xsl:value-of select="$remoteClientAddress" />
```

But in configuration.xml file I use this :

```
<logger message="Remote client address is------> #[remoteClientAddress]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

for checking IP-Address, but in my MULE Console I saw this statement : /127.0.0.1:51708
while I need to **127.0.0.1** I don't need **/** before ip-address and **:51708** at the end of my ip-address.

How can I remove these extra parts in Configuration.xml in mule and then just send 
ip-address to .xslt file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about Mule, but you could just do this:

```
<xsl:param  name="remoteClientAddress" />
<xsl:variable name="remoteClientAddressTrimmed"
       select="substring-before(substring-after($remoteClientAddress, '/'), ':')" />
```

and then later

```
<xsl:value-of select="$remoteClientAddressTrimmed" />
```